# insert list of records?

Tags: rest

i am tring to insert list of account records using dto class...

```
list<dtoaccount> a = (list<dtoaccount>)JSON.deserialize(body.toString(),dtoaccount.class);
```

i used this code for converting json body here "dtoaccount" is Wrapperclass but i am getting error:

> "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
>               "message": "System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type accountinsertion.dtoaccount to
>   List\n\nClass.accountinsertion.postaccount:
>   line 11, column 1"

wrapper class:

```
public class dtoaccount{
public string name{get;set;}
public string Phone{get;set;}
public string type{get;set;}
public string Industry{get;set;}

public dtoaccount(string name,string Phone,string type,string Industry){
this.Name = Name;
this.Phone = Phone;
this.type = type;
this.Industry = Industry;
}
}
```

body:

```
{
"name":"xyz",
"Phone":"123456789",
  "type" : "prospect",
  "Industry" : "banking"
  }
```

Comment: Can you pls add `body.toString()` and `dtoaccount` ? so we can compare what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for responding can you please check updated code

Answer (score 2):

If the JSON really is a list/array (starts with `[`) the code would need to be:

```
List<dtoaccount> a = (List<dtoaccount>) JSON.deserialize(
        body.toString(),
        List<dtoaccount>.class
        );
```

and if the JSON is a single object (starts with `{`) the code would need to be:

```
dtoaccount a = (dtoaccount) JSON.deserialize(
        body.toString(),
        dtoaccount.class
        );
```

**PS**

Based on your update to the question it should be the latter.

Comment: i used this code even i m getting error:"errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
        "message": "System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set\n\nClass.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1\nClass.accountinsertion.postaccount: line 11, column 1"

Comment: @user123 Using the second piece of code or the first?

Comment: i need to insert list of account records i used first piece of code only

Comment: @user123 Your JSON appears to be a single item not a list of those items. Change the code that generates the JSON to be working with a list and then you can use the first first piece of code.

Comment: could you please tell me example code for list of records in json formate in body

Comment: @user123 Sure, just put square brackets around your object i.e. `[{...}]`. Please also spend a few minutes reading this [JSON](http://www.json.org/) page - that is the entire spec of JSON - it is very simple.